# CSV file order by columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a .CSV file:

```
0.04081632653061224,0.02209708691207961,0.02040816326530612,0.02209708691207961
```

how do I order it by columns?

Example:

```
Velocity
0.04081632653061224
0.02209708691207961
0.02040816326530612
0.02209708691207961
```

Comment: Hello Yestex, welcome to stackoverflow. please see this post on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using Pandas to accomplish this. It can be installed by running `pip install pandas`. Then run the following script:

```
Import pandas as pd
x = pd.read_csv("foo.csv")
x = x.sort_values(by=["Velocity"], ascending=False)
x.to_csv("sorted_foo.csv")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just read the file as a string and split it by the comma.

```
data = "0.02209708691207961,0.02040816326530612,0.02209708691207961,0.04081632653061224"

datalist = [ float(x) for x in data.split(",") ]
datalist.sort(reverse=True)

print(datalist)
```